# Как определить архитектуру компьютера на Windows?

Tags: windows, железо, ноутбук

Хотел скачать .NET SDK, но надо выбрать, какая у меня архитектура: x86, x64, или ARM. Если что, то модель компьютера – ASUS Vivobook 15 M513UA-BN725W, на Windows 11 home single language

Comment: С 99.9% вероятностью x64

Comment: Пуск — Панель управления — Система — Тип системы.

Comment: ...а хотя учитывая, что x86-версии Windows 11 не бывает, а в этом ноутбуке стоит AMD Ryzen, то уже со 100% вероятностью x64

Comment: Спасибо большое, всем!